# Need to find which players played in which year(s) using R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have baseball data and need to find which players --

1. played in 1945 but not 1946.
2. did not play in either year.
3. played in both 1945 and 1946.

**For #1, the desired output would be --**

```
player  
Albert
Barnes
```

For #2, the desired output would be --

```
player
Andrews
David
```

**For #3, the desired output would be --**

```
player
Baker
Frank
```

I would prefer a **dplyr** solution but am open to others. I could not find a solution in stackoverflow that matched my situation. If one exists, I would appreciate it if you could share its link.

**Input sample**
[image]

**Dput data sample**

```
structure(list(player = c("Albert", "Andrews", "Baker", "Charles", 
"Baker", "David", "Frank", "Barnes", "Ross", "Frank", "Frank"
), year = c(1945, 1944, 1946, 1946, 1945, 1947, 1945, 1945, 1946, 
1946, 1947)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```

Comment: I'd `pivot_wider()` the years first so then it'd be easier to `filter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
dat <- structure(list(player = c("Albert", "Andrews", "Baker", "Charles", 
                                 "Baker", "David", "Frank", "Barnes", "Ross", "Frank", "Frank"
), year = c(1945, 1944, 1946, 1946, 1945, 1947, 1945, 1945, 1946, 
            1946, 1947)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))


dat %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  filter(1945 %in% year  & ! 1946 %in% year) %>% 
  select(player) 
#> # A tibble: 2 × 1
#> # Groups:   player [2]
#>   player
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 Albert
#> 2 Barnes

  
dat %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  filter(! 1945 %in% year  & ! 1946 %in% year) %>% 
  select(player) 
#> # A tibble: 2 × 1
#> # Groups:   player [2]
#>   player 
#>   <chr>  
#> 1 Andrews
#> 2 David


dat %>% 
  group_by(player) %>% 
  filter(all(c(1945, 1946) %in% year)) %>% 
  select(player) %>% 
  distinct()
#> # A tibble: 2 × 1
#> # Groups:   player [2]
#>   player
#>   <chr> 
#> 1 Baker 
#> 2 Frank
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: In `filter(all(c(1945, 1946) %in% year))` what purpose does `all` serve?

Comment: Since you have two years, `c(1945, 1946) %in% year` will generate two logical values.  You want to know when they're both `TRUE` so `all(c(1945, 1946) %in% year)` is `TRUE` if both years are in `year` and `FALSE` otherwise.  Without `all()` the filter statement doesn't work.